# What exactly bind API do in Server program

Tags: c++

what exactly bind api doing in server programm.
I am very new for socket programming.
Bind says : bind the socket to IPaddress and port.
So what exactly happen if i give 
argument1 of bind=AF_INET & args2=(sockaddr *)struct sockaddr hint and  args3=sizeof(hint);

Comment: Can you please include a small example program that illustrates the usage you don't understand? You might consider reviewing [ask] to include the necessary details in your question.

Comment: It binds the socket to a local IP address and port number, so that you can put it into listen mode and have clients connect to it at that IP:port. Otherwise you would get a random port or possibly an error on `listen()`.

Comment: @user207421 I'm trying to give polite advice on how to ask a good question, which I think is reasonable. I didn't downvote; I gave the asker a chance to improve the question, make it more answerable and more useful to other people. Probably you are right, but at the same time I suspect the asker has at least read a summary and may be confused about some specific aspect. Also, this question could quite legitimately be about [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), for example being used to create asynchronous callback functors.

Comment: @BoBTFish You are giving the *incorrect* advice that a general question need specific source code.

Comment: @user207421 This is not a general question. It is an unclear and possibly too broad question. Code is not required, but it may help _a lot_ to clarify what is actually asked about. But yes, in some cases you can also clarify a question with raw text.

Comment: @BoBTFish The applicable code is as follows: `int rc = ::bind(sd, &sa, sizeof sa);`. Does that really make the question easier to understand? I thought not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: bind() specifies the address & port on the local side of the connection. If you don't call bind(), the operating system will automatically assign you an available port number.

Each time an IP datagram containing TCP data is sent over the network, the datagram contains a 'local address', 'remote address', 'local port', and 'remote port'. This is the only information that IP has to figure out who ends up getting the packet.

So, both the client and the server port numbers need to be filled in before the connection can work. Data that is directed to the server needs a 'destination' port, so that the data can get sent to the appropriate program running on the server. Likewise, it needs a 'source' so that the server knows who to send data back to, and also so that if there are many connections from the same computer, the server can keep them separate by looking at the source port number.

Since the connection is initiated by the client program, the client program needs to know the server's port number before it can make a connection. For this reason, servers are placed on 'well-known' port numbers. For example, a telnet server is always on port 23. A http server is always on port 80.

The bind() API call assigns the 'local' port number. That is, the port number that is used as the 'source port' on outgoing datagrams, and the 'destination port' on incoming datagrams.

There is a detailed explanation [here](https://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/bindapi.html) with an example.

Comment: Good answer to a bad question :-)

Comment: I apologize to give bad explanation for question. I was confused about my question, bcz before that i never work with socket programming. But Thanks for  explaining well.I think now i am little clear abt bind api.

Comment: @Nic3500 Bad question why? It's answerable from the documentation, in theory, but I would have to state that the Sockets API gave me more trouble than any other so far in 48 years of computer programming. Once you understand all the documentation and the protocols and RFCs it makes sense, but the *man* pages alone are really not sufficient.